# Difference between navigateRight and focusRightGroup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the difference between these two command IDs in VSCode?

- `workbench.action`.**navigateRight**
- `workbench.action`.**focusRightGroup**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `navigateRight` moves the cursor focus to the window to the right in the layout of the app.
- `focusRightGroup` moves the focus to the window to the right editor group in the editor.